# How to use Highslide Iframe popup and ESCape button?

Tags: highslide

I open a Highslide popup using an Iframe. I need to close it with the ESCape key. It works great when I do something out Iframe. But when I click on something in the Iframe and then press the ESCape button, it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: We need more information about the content of your iframe popup: what is this “something” you're clicking in the iframe that makes the ESC button not working. Do you have a live page where we can see the this problem?

Comment: Live example

http://primopiter.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82/1-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5.html

Click on palnning and you see popup frame. If you click after ESC button, then popup does not close.

Answer (score 1):

You can not close the popup with the ESC key when `hs.enableKeyListener` is set to `false` in your highslide.config.js file.
You need to remove this line from your highslide.config.js file:

```
hs.enableKeyListener = false;
```